# Is there a way when the div inside expands, the outer div also opens

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is there a way when the div inside expands, the outer div also opens

```
<div id="div-parent">
  <div id="div-child1"></div>
  <div id="div-child2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to add a snippet of what you did until now

Comment: What do you mean by `expands` and `opens`  - please show expected output

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please do read the [tour] and the [ask] page.

Comment: As comment above (what is "opens") but also how are you currently "expanding" the inner div?

Comment: Also JAVA is not JavaScript

Comment: most likely the author means the correspondence in width and height of the parent div relative to the child div